# Attempt to print array element returns "Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC. occurred"

Tags: c++, arrays, exception, memory-management

This code is for a project that when given a text file such as this:

```
14.99 24 Hat
29.99 31 Shirt
17.99 12 Shorts
5.50 18 Socks
-1 -1 endofdata
```

should print out a "receipt" of sorts, but I am getting an exception at line 73 (put an all caps comment there) when I try to print array[i].name. 
I tried to change it to &array[i].name (along with other elements I try to print) and it prints the addresses just fine. 
I would really appreciate your help. Code is displayed below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct prod {
    string name;
    float price;
    int inStock;
};

void swapName(string* name1, string* name2) {
    string temp = *name1;
    *name1 = *name2;
    *name2 = temp;
}

prod readInventory(prod array[], int max) {
    ifstream inventoryF("inventory.txt");
    if (inventoryF.fail()) {
        cout << "Unable to open input file.\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            array[i].price = 0;
            array[i].inStock = 0;
            array[i].name = " ";
        }
    }
    else {
        int i = 0;
        while (array[i].price > 0) {

            inventoryF>> array[i].price;
            inventoryF >> array[i].inStock;
            inventoryF >>array[i].name;
            i += 1;
        } 
        cout << "Inventory read."<< endl;
    }
    return *array;
}

float totalValue(prod array[]) {
    int i = 0;
    float total = 0;
    while (array[i].price> 0) {
        total+=array[i].price* array[i].inStock;
        i++;
    }
    return total;
}

prod sortByName(prod array[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (array[i].name > array[i + 1].name) {
            swapName(&array[i].name, &array[i + 1].name);
        }
    }
    cout << "Poducts sorted by name.\n";
    return *array;
}

void writeReport(prod array[],int max) {
    cout <<setprecision(2)<< "+---------------------------+" << endl;
    cout << "|     Current Inventory     |" << endl;
    cout << "+---------------------------+" << endl;
    cout << left << setw(15) << "NAME" << setw(12) << "PRICE" << "#" << endl;
    cout << "------------  -------     ---" << endl;
    int j = 0;
    float total = totalValue(array);
    for (int i =0;i< max;i++){
        //PROBLEM IS ON THE LINE BELOW
        cout << left << setw(15) << array[i].name << setw(2) << "$" << array[i].price<< right << array[i].inStock<< endl;
        j++;
    }
    cout << "+---------------------------+" << endl;
    cout << left << setw(22) << "Number of products:" << j << endl;
    cout << setw(22) << "Inventory total value:" << total << endl;;
}


int main() {
    const int prodMax = 20;
    int current = 0;
    prod productArray[prodMax];
    prod temp = readInventory(productArray, prodMax);
    //temp = sortByName(&temp);
    writeReport(&temp, prodMax);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [0xCC means you're accessing uninitialized memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Answer (score 1):

Your `readInventory()` function is inherently flawed. you're returning the initial product of an array of products. if you wanted to return the whole array, you'd need to make `readInventory` return prod* and change from `return *array` to just `return array`. Meaning, by passing &temp to `writeReport()` you're passing an array of 1 product, of course causing a read access violation.

Comment: Also you can't print a string without including <string>

Comment: And don't use plain arrays, if you need const size array, use `std::array` and if you need array with changeable size, use `std::vector`.

Comment: It is pointless to return an input argument in the first place. The function can simply be `void`.

Comment: That is true. really i just wanted to find a solution and as soon as i found it i just put a fix together in a couple of seconds. of course one would need to settle down to design everything correctly but this is not codereview lol.

Comment: Thank you. It is my first question on here and your solution worked. We were not allowed to use vectors, so I had to stick with arrays. Is it in all cases that changing the function to a pointer allows you to return the value instead of the reference?

Comment: Changing the function to return a pointer lets you return a pointer. if you want to return a reference, just put & next to the return type. When you want to return an array, you have to return a pointer of the array type, in this case prod*. that's because arrays are just pointers, after all. You might wanna read up on memory and c++ data types/structures.